# How can I produce __dirname pointing to the root directory from within an EJS module located in a subdirectory?

Tags: node.js, dirname

I am using EJS modules and would like to refer to all files with reference to the root directory. In the past, this would be __dirname, but per this description it is different.  These instructions are helpful (https://blog.logrocket.com/alternatives-dirname-node-js-es-modules/)  but I still cannot seem to find the right combination.

For example, I have test.mjs in the root directory and test2.mjs in the scripts directory (scripts/test2.mjs)

test.mjs

```
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import { dirname } from "node:path";
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
console.log("test.mjs produces " + __dirname)
```

output

```
test.mjs produces rootdir
```

scripts/test2.mjs

```
import {fileURLToPath} from 'url';
import { dirname } from "node:path";
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
console.log("test2.mjs produces " + __dirname)
```

output

```
test2.mjs produces rootdir/scripts
```

Comment: What do you mean by "root directory"?   `__dirname` was ALWAYS the directory that the currently executing script is located in.  It can be different from different scripts all being used in the same program as `__dirname` is a script-specific variable.  You can get the equivalent using the method you show in test2.mjs.  That works.  If by root directory, you mean the directory of the root script that launched the program, that is different and you can get that from any script in your program by doing `const appRootScriptDir = dirname(process.argv[1])`.

Comment: By root directory in this case I wanted to get "rootdir" in both cases. This is the location of index.mjs and package.json. Interestingly, your solution produces the directory above the root in both cases. Odd, but at least it is consistent. That will work!  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path of the initial script that launched the app is in:

```
process.argv[1]
```

And, this is accessible from any script in your project, no matter where its located and it always returns the same filename.

So, if you want to strip the filename off and get just the directory of that initial script, you can do this:

```
import { dirname } from "node:path";

const rootDir = dirname(process.argv[1]);
```

Depending upon how your project's scripts are structured and which exact directory in that structure you want, you may want to go up or down from this directory, but it at least gives you a know and consistent location in your structure that is accessible from any script in the project.

Comment: Yup! That did the trick!

Comment: done! i did not see a checkmark the first time. i was the upvote.

Comment: For me this is not a solution, because i start within the project root with `npm run rootdir/scripts/test2.mjs` and i would like become the project root dir. This is needed because my html is located in `rootdir/html/index.html` and contains references to test2.mjs